# Rails and RSpec: be_successful vs have_http_status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

From what I can see `be_successful` is core Rails and `have_http_status` is part of RSpec.

Is there any performance difference (or what is the preferred convention) between:

```
expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
expect(response).to be_successful
```

Thanks

Comment: `be_successful` is a combination of `be` matcher from rspec-expectations gem and `successful?` helper method from rack gem.

Answer (score 2):

To your question of performance, there is no difference. Any slight variation in string comparisons or stack depth between the two will be trivial compared to the work of creating and processing the hit to your controller. If you're battling slow tests, focus on avoiding database writes (e.g. Model.build instead of Model.create) and mocking out methods to classes outside the class you're testing.

Aesthetically, I think `expect(response).to be_successful` is more to the point. Future updates (or even the current implementation) to `be_successful` may add more insightful tests or feedback than just `http_status == 200`.

I'd only use the status value check if you were specifically interested in that number for some reason, versus the concept of a successful hit.

Answer (score 2):

`have_http_status` will show a more specific/friendlier error message if there's a mismatch, which is helpful for debugging. As the previous answer noted, the performance difference is negligible in the grand scheme of your test suite.

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  expected the response to have a success status code (2xx) but it was 400
```

vs.

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to be_successful
  expected `#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x00005650d1daf0e8 @mon_data=#<Monitor:0x00005650d1daeb98>, @mon_data_..., @method=nil, @request_method=nil, @remote_ip=nil, @original_fullpath=nil, @fullpath=nil, @ip=nil>>.successful?` to return true, got false
```

Comment: aesthetically I prefer `be_successful` but the better error message of `have_http_status`is better.